# Publish snapshot Jar in codeArtifact returns bad request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, snapshot, aws-codeartifact

I am starting to evaluate AWS codeArtifact service. Currently I am hosting maven artifacts in an on-premises Nexus repository. We use snapshots and release artifacts as expected using gradle to describe project's dependencies and repositories to work with. I added the following code section to the gradle file. Version parameter is being hardcoded for testing purposes.

```
    publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${codeArtifactUrl}"
            credentials {
                username "aws"
                password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the gradle publish task it is returning me the following:

```
Could not find metadata com.turner.lrs.packages:lrs-packages-commons:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in remote (https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/)
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0-20220914.171546-1.jar
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0-20220914.171546-1.jar.sha1
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0-20220914.171546-1.jar.md5
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0-20220914.171546-1.pom
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0-20220914.171546-1.pom.sha1
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0-20220914.171546-1.pom.md5
Could not find metadata com.turner.lrs.packages:lrs-packages-commons/maven-metadata.xml in remote (https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/)
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/maven-metadata.xml

> Task :lrs-packages-commons:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository 
Could not transfer metadata com.turner.lrs.packages:lrs-packages-commons:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to remote (https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/): Could not write to resource 'com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'
Could not transfer metadata com.turner.lrs.packages:lrs-packages-commons/maven-metadata.xml from/to remote (https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/): Could not write to resource 'com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/maven-metadata.xml'


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lrs-packages-commons:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven'
   > Could not write to resource 'https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
      > Could not PUT 'https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

[image]

The jar ends up being published but with an "Unfinished" status

However if I remove the word SNAPSHOT, everything works as expected, artifact is published and its status is "Published"

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            version = '1.0.0'
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${codeArtifactUrl}"
            credentials {
                username "aws"
                password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0.jar
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0.jar.sha1
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0.jar.md5
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0.pom
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0.pom.sha1
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/1.0.0/lrs-packages-commons-1.0.0.pom.md5
Could not find metadata com.turner.lrs.packages:lrs-packages-commons/maven-metadata.xml in remote (https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/)
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/maven-metadata.xml
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Upload https://gmsc-esb-817672308881.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/esb/com/turner/lrs/packages/lrs-packages-commons/maven-metadata.xml.md5

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
```

[image]

Any clue?